# asp.net Custom Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am rly confused about this.
I tried following all kind of tutorials but cant seem to get it working right
I dont know what I am doing wrong sinse its the exact same as those vids I Have seen.

I tried this

web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx"/>
```

changing the application_error under Global.aspx.cs

where it ends out with a respons redirect also tried server transfer but none of them leads me to my Error.aspx

does someone know a good simple tutorial on how to set one up? or someone who can tell me step by step what to do?

I tried following the first part of this [guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wObqULbm5g) sinse that is what I wanted.

```
        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Redirect(@"~Error.aspx");
    }
```

but it tells me it goes into an infinite loop.

I want to send the user to a page called Error.aspx where they can see a custom error screen.

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: edited it now so you can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IIS prob will be the next problem xD hehe
but I found the source to my loop and problem

I had this code inside my Error.aspx and that made it crash aka loop xD

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server" >
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open IIS.
2. Select your website on the left side from Sites.
3. Double click on .Net error pages.
4. Select Edit Feature setting from Action pane on the right side.
5. Select On and give the name of your page which you want to display
   when any error occurs.

I followed following steps and have not added anything in Global.asax and it is working fine for me.
Just try this and remove code from global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" >
         <remove statusCode="500" />
         <error statusCode="500"
            prefixLanguageFilePath="C:\Contoso\Content\errors"
            path="500.htm" />
       </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Otherwise, follow these steps at IIS level

HOW TO ADD A CUSTOM ERROR PAGE

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
...

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
                  defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" />

    ...
</system.web>
```

Note the leading ~ for path resolution